# How do I find an active class and move it to a parent container using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, drupal-6, jquery-1.3

When an active class is present on the `<a>`, I would like to move that class up to it's highest parent; the `<div class="views-row">`

```
<div class="views-row-unformatted views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="title">
    <span class="field-content">
      <a class="active">
        <h3>Title Text</h3>
      </a>
    </span>    
  </div>
</div>
```

I am limited to working in the theme layer and have only jQuery and CSS as my tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:has` selector or `has` method:

```
$('div.views-row:has(a.active)') 
                   .addClass('active') 
                   .find('a.active') 
                   .removeClass('active');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RmxWq/

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile and providing a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

use `:has()` , `parents()` and `addClass()`.

```
$('a:has(".active")').parents('div.views-row').addClass('active');
```